# Cross domain workaround for @font-face and Firefox for AWS S3

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3, font-face

Does anyone know some fixes for cross domain complications for Firefox and using @fontface with Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just ended up uploading my fontface files on heroku itself. I know its not an ideal approach, but for now seemed the best option to me

Comment: Did you add a crossdomain.xml file to the root of your bucket? Then access that bucket via its DNS-style URL?

Comment: I will defiantly try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Log into your Amazon S3 Console - https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3
2. Select a bucket from your account. Open the "Permissions" drop down.
3. Click "Add CORS Configuration". Change the configuration to match
   your requirements. In this case, to allow a simple GET request to
   access our Font i setup the following:.

   ```
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
       <CORSRule>
           <AllowedOrigin>http://mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
           <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
           <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
           <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
       </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```

you can change allowedOrigin to * instead of http://mydomain.com if you want to allow access from any origin.
Sometime you need to do another step:

Expire your assets and recompile them from the Rake task. This is required in order for the new CORS configuration to take action.